# $H^n(G,M)$ with a cyclic $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I have to show that $H^n( \text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{q^d}/\mathbb{F}_q),\mathbb{F}_{q^d}^{\times})=0$ if $n\geq 1$.

I suppose I have to use the fact that if $G$ is cyclic generated by $\phi$ and $M$ is a $G$-module, then $$H^k(G,M)= \begin{cases}
M^{N=0}/(\phi-1)(M) & k\geq 1 \text{ odd} \\
M^{\phi}/ N(M) &k \geq 2 \text{ even,}
\end{cases} $$
where $N= 1 +\phi+\phi^2+\dots+\phi^{d-1}$, $M^{\phi}=\{ m\in M \ | \ \phi(m)=m \}$ and $M^{N=0} = \{ m \in M \ | \ N(m) = 0_M \}$, but I don't know how.